# How to find a parmetrization of..

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

..of this curve $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z=x^2$ anticlockwise from (1,0,1) to (-1,0,1).
I sort of understand how to find a parmetrization when the curve is simpler but here I'm lost.

Comment: What do you mean by a parameterisation of two different curves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take

- $x=\cos t$
- $y=\sin t$
- $z=\cos^2 t$

now we need to find a correct range for $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized in polar angle $\theta,$ the space curve with periodic repetition for all integers $n:$

$$ (x,y,z) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, \cos^2 \theta),(0<\theta <2 n \pi) $$

Comment: is the range for t P[0,pi] -> C?